# How to configure one-finger touchpad scroll if some hotkey is pressed?

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch, scrolling

I often use thumbs to control cursor via touchpad while doing 10-finger touch typing. On Windows and macOS I can configure one finger scroll: if some hotkey is pressed I move thumb over the touchpad to scroll up, down, left and right. This is handy since I don't need to move my entire hand in order for 2-finger scroll.

Is it possible to somehow configure the same behaviour with the latest Ubuntu desktop? I know about the "1-finger edge scrolling" but I want 1-finger scroll for the entire touchpad while hotkey is pressed, since touchpad edges are hard to reach without removing my hand(s) from the 10-finger touch typing position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Customization options are limited with `libinput` in Wayland ... But, the following should work out of the box ...

Enable two-finger scrolling for your touchpad:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/peripherals/touchpad/two-finger-scrolling-enabled "true"
```

... and use your other thumb as a trigger (hotkey/hot-thumb) by simply placing it on the touchpad ... That is e.g. left thumb moving on the touchpad will move the pointer but, if you do that while your right thumb is touching and holding on the touchpad, then that will change your left thumb movements up/down and left/right into scrolling action instead.

**Notice** that your mileage may vary depending on the sensitivity of your touchpad hardware.

Comment: That's genius! Doesn't work this way on macOS and Windows so I didn't even tried. But indeed, if both fingers touch the touchpad it's enough to move just one of them !